# This line of code for css animation dont run on safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari, css-animations

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #00A14B;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.st1 {
  fill: green;
  -webkit-animation: usage 2s normal forwards;
  animation: usage 2s normal forward;
}
@-webkit-keyframes usage {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 72%;
  }
}
@keyframes usage {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 72%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g id="stroker">
    <polygon class="st0" points="39.395,10.166 39.395,2.02 25.898,2.02 25.898,10.166 5.404,10.166 5.404,102.403 59.89,102.403 59.89,10.166 " />
    <rect x="25.898" y="2.02" width="13.755" height="9.839" />

  </g>
  <g id="filler">

    <rect x="6.96" y="11.335" class="st1" width="51.374" height="88" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

What my goal is to animate the fill of the battery from top to bottom, to indicate the level of usage. After many attempts I can't seem to make it work on safari.

Basically I just want the red fill for the battery to turn green, this is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3vpkq899/3/
seems need change `height` in `@keyframes` to `transform: scaleY(100%)`